# Extracting tweets using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, python-3.6

I'm writing a Python code to extract tweets from a twitter account. I'm having a bit of trouble at the moment.

Below is my code *(I'm removed my cosumer and access ID for this)*:

```
import csv
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    alltweets = []  

    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print ("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print ("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_all_tweets("hello")
```

When I run it, I get this error:

[image]

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Check permissions of your file. It seems the python program can't open it

Comment: @ThrowsException I looked at the permissions for my file and all the boxes has been checked under "Allow" (except "Special permissions"). Should I take a screenshot of what I'm talking about?

Comment: Windows file permissions can be iffy at best. Try running the python shell as administrator and see if that alleviates the issue.

Comment: @ThrowsException I see. I'm currently running my program via Notepad++. I'll try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: @ThrowsException I just ran my file on command line and it has output the csv file, but there's no content in there. Plus I get a slightly different error. Take a look here: https://i.imgbox.com/YxyiX3n0.png Any help with this?

Comment: @ThrowsException It works now! I simply removed the "b" from `with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb')`. So the code reads like: `with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w')`. I took an advice from someone on github.

Answer (score 0):

**Just close the opened file where you are going to write.**

Here it is **hello_tweets.csv**

Comment: Are you talking about the file that contains my python code?

Comment: No a csv file would have been created once you run the program. And THAT file would be open!. Or you would have a **hello_tweets.csv** open in the same directory.  Try giving a different twitter account name instead of "hello".

Comment: I tried a different account name (RelicCastleCom) and still doesn't work. I'm currently running my program with Notepad++, do you think that may be the problem?

Comment: My code is outputting a csv file now, when I run it on command line, but the csv file is empty. Plus I get this error: https://i.imgbox.com/YxyiX3n0.png Any advise on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have permission to open the file and permission to read/write in the folder.

I wouldn't recommend it, but if you NEED to run the code and can't find the issue, try doing it as admin.

Comment: The file (which contains my code) is on my computer. I would assume everything should be okay? Plus how can I run the code as an admin? I'm currently running my code through Notepad++

Comment: If you're using a notepad++ plugin, then run notepad++ as admin.
Did you create the file in the code, or did you create it as a user and then run the code? Creating the file with python might solve it.

Comment: I typed up a code in a file and saved said file as a .py file. Here is a screenshot of how I am running the file. i.imgbox.com/bgg97Khf.png Is this a proper way of running the file?

Comment: I've ran the program on command line and it outputs a csv file, but when I open it, it's empty. Plus, I get this error: https://i.imgbox.com/YxyiX3n0.png Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't know how writer.writerow() works, but you could try with `for out in outtweets: writer.write("%d\t%s\t%s\n" % (out[1], out[2], out[3]))`. This might, though, increase the computation time, but I'm not sure how writelines works, so I'm suggesting what I know...

Comment: Should I delete `writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
  writer.writerows(outtweets)` and replace it with your code?

Comment: Instead of writer.write, use `f.write(code)` That should do it.